# synchronizing two process in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my problem is i have two different function running with ajax call in them which makes them asynchronous. I have to fire third function when both gets completed. issue is being async nature i can know when both of them are ending. there are solutions like :

1. making them sync
2. putting one in the success of other,

but this both will cause delay because these ajax calls are bringing big data so its better to have them async.

Can somebody suggest me any cleaner way for doing this.

```
function f1(){
//AJAX call}

function f2(){
//ajax call}

when f1 and f2 are done fire f3().
```

Comment: You can try with $.when() or $.deferred of jquery

Answer (score 1):

I think what your are looking for is jQuery.done(): https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Example:

```
// 3 functions to call when the Deferred object is resolved
function fn1() {
$( "p" ).append( " 1 " );
}
function fn2() {
$( "p" ).append( " 2 " );
}
function fn3( n ) {
$( "p" ).append( n + " 3 " + n );
}
// Create a deferred object
var dfd = $.Deferred();
// Add handlers to be called when dfd is resolved
dfd
// .done() can take any number of functions or arrays of functions
.done( [ fn1, fn2 ], fn3, [ fn2, fn1 ] )
// We can chain done methods, too
.done(function( n ) {
$( "p" ).append( n + " we're done." );
});
// Resolve the Deferred object when the button is clicked
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
dfd.resolve( "and" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.when( f1(), f2() ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the f1() and f2() ajax requests, respectively.

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var async1 = $.get('hello.php');
var async2 = $.get('world.php');

$.when(async1, async2).done(function(hello, world) {
    // this function will be called only if async1 and async2 are resolved
    console.log(hello);
    console.log(world);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/